# Synchronizing 10 threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Why do I get

22291 3091 0 351 0 1423 0 0 0 0

and not

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

when I run this code in Java:

```
import java.lang.Thread;

class MainThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) new MyThread().start();
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    static int counter = 0;
    static Object mutex = new Object();
    public void run() {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) counter = counter + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) counter = counter - 1;
        }
        System.out.print(counter + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the `print` is not synchronized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that output because print statement is not syncronized. After a `thread` finishes two for loop and exists from the `syncronized` block, the `counter = 0`.
But before it prints out the `counter` some other thread get into the `syncronized` block and starts incrementing the `counter`.
That's why the previous `thread` prints the incremented `counter`.

```
public void run() {
    synchronized (mutex) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) counter = counter + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) counter = counter - 1;
    }
    // Here the current thread exited the sync block and some other thread get into this block  
    // and started incrementing the counter

    System.out.print(counter + " "); // your thread prints incremented counter
}
```